# What is the value of schema tests in dbt?

Tags: sql, validation, testing, dbt

When would you want to use a [dbt schema tests](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/tests#generic-tests) (`unique`, `not_null`, `accepted_values`, & `relationships`) when you could instead use SQL schema constraints?

For example, here are some SQL schema constraints that could replace each of the dbt schema tests:

- `unique`: [`UNIQUE` constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)
- `not_null`: [`NOT NULL` constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_notnull.asp)
- `accepted_values`: [`FOREIGN KEY` constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) to a lookup table
- `relationships`: [`FOREIGN KEY` constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) to another table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have the above-listed table constraints on a view, or a CTE. The value of dbt is that users are allowed to build a DAG of `SELECT` queries without having to worry about DDL or configuration. At a later point of time they can be configured to be tables instead of the default view, and no syntax need be changed.

Answer (score 4):

dbt tests are more flexible than database constraints. If you try to insert a null value to a not null target your process will fail, end of story. With dbt tests you can execute first, test after, which might be interesting.

More examples:

- You can classify tests are warnings instead of errors
- You can define error thresholds
- You can specify a filter to apply the test only to a subset of values
- Test can behave differently in different environments (prod/dev etc.)
- dbt tests are easier to modify than database contraints